# how to remove property from javascript without loosing it in original object

Tags: javascript

How to remove property from javascript without loosing it in original object?
I mean that I can do like this:

```
var originalObject = ...;
```

`delete originalObject["Undefined"]` and it would remove property `originalObject.Undefined`, however, I don't want originalObject to be changed. I wish like this:

```
newObject = removeUndefined(originalObject);
```

Comment: You first need to clone the original object to new and then delete the property from it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to clone an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)

Comment: @Typo This question is half of the answer.

Comment: @VisioN yep, but there's no half flagged option

Comment: @Typo Then you can use that question as a part of your answer or a comment for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object/122190#122190) question you have how to clone the object, as stated in one of the answers "Assuming that you have only variables and not any functions in your object":

you could define:

```
function removeUndefined(originalObject){

    var newObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalObject));
    delete newObject['Undefined'];
    return newObject;
}
```

So later you could call:

```
newObject = removeUndefined(originalObject);
```